# Al utilizar implicit operator genera un StackOverflowException

Tags: c#

Buen día. Me encuentro con el siguiente código:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// implicit model
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="document"></param>
        public static implicit operator DocumentViewModel(Document document)
        {
            return new Document
            {
                Id = document.Id,
            };
        }
    }
```

Se utiliza de la siguiente manera:

```
DocumentViewModel results;
            try
            {
                using (var context = new DbContext())
                {
                    var uow = new DocumentUoW(context);
                    Document doc = uow.FindById(id);
                    results = doc; //aquí me da el StackOverFlowException
                }
                return Ok(results);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
```

Al llamar al DocumentViewModel, genera la siguiente excepción en la conversión explícita:

```
System.StackOverflowException: 'Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.StackOverflowException'.'
```

El error no muestra InnerException o StackTrace a rastrear, el depurador apenas llega ahí lanza el error. No entiendo porqué está pasando, estoy tratando de investigar pero la descripción del error es demasiado genérica para encontrar algo que me ayude. ¿Alguien tiene una idea de qué pasa?

Comment: Pon la excepción completa dentro de la pregunta, por favor. Lo otro es que no sé si las variables sean case-sensitive y ese `id` no esté atado al `Id` del modelo

Comment: ¡listo! recordaba que lo puse jajaja, gracias

Comment: respecto a lo tro que mencionas, la línea `Document doc = uow.FindById(id);` sí me devuelve datos, la línea que sigue es la que genera el error.

Comment: ya se cual es el problema :p .. si tu conversion implicita, no devuelve un DocumentViewModel, se la va a pasar llamandola eternamente.. no?

Comment: pfff, te juro que llevaba un rato dándole vueltas y no daba con el clavo, cuando la respuesta estaba frente a mis ojos todo el rato! jajajaja, muchas gracias @gbianchi , si era eso

Comment: pongan la respuesta! :D

Comment: arreglalo, explica el problema, y pone la respuesta, que aunque no lo creas, es interesante...

Comment: listo, ya hay respuesta! :D

Comment: +1 por publicar este problema en stackoverflow, impresionante...   :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probemos el siguiente código en [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/awodnC) (es solo un código para emular el problema):

```cs
using System;

class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class DocumentViewModel
{
      public static implicit operator DocumentViewModel(Document document)
      {
           return new Document
           {
               Id = document.Id,
           };
      }
 }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DocumentViewModel results;
        Document doc = new Document();
        results = doc; 
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar el programa, nos da el siguiente resultado:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 130903 times:
--------------------------------
   at DocumentViewModel.op_Implicit(Document)
--------------------------------
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

Con nuestra intuición podemos deducir que el problema está en esta línea pero no tenemos la más minima idea del porque está sucediendo un [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow):

```cs
results = doc;
```

Para saber con más detalle que es lo que realmente está pasando, vamos a convertir el código C# a código IL usando [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/). Haga clic en este [enlace](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQO0AIARAewGMBXAWwFMA7YHAbxwEhkBmfZdABnwEkY+RvgDm1YAG58AZwnSAvjiW5sBEhRr0AamGoB3ALLEY1CExz4r1jl3QA2fGEoAHCGFJhg+Yi+oAnAENgYn8iMio6YF0DY1MIAAoNSPp8GAitYABKS2srZmw8oqtkAHZ8WgNwzSjc4usC+qbBfABeNIyogDpBKDqmhUl+qxV8FTxOAm5Si2w2VFRWApYWZMyYoxMzfH9qGXIIYBkhudXO1PTSNoqqtaiErJOm3f3DmWvL6VYVBSA==) para ver el código IL.

Al final solo nos interesa esta parte del código IL generado:

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit DocumentViewModel
    extends [System.Private.CoreLib]System.Object
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig specialname static 
        class DocumentViewModel op_Implicit (
            class Document document
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x206c
        // Code size 29 (0x1d)
        .maxstack 3
        .locals init (
            [0] class DocumentViewModel
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: newobj instance void Document::.ctor()
        IL_0006: dup
        IL_0007: ldarg.0
        IL_0008: callvirt instance string Document::get_Id()
        IL_000d: callvirt instance void Document::set_Id(string)
        IL_0012: nop
        // El causante del error es esta línea:
        IL_0013: call class DocumentViewModel DocumentViewModel::op_Implicit(class Document) // Aquí sucede una recursión infinita, sin fin...
        IL_0018: stloc.0
        IL_0019: br.s IL_001b

        IL_001b: ldloc.0
        IL_001c: ret
    } // end of method DocumentViewModel::op_Implicit
```

El código IL anterior lo podemos traducir a C# para entender mejor lo que está haciendo el compilador:

```cs
class DocumentViewModel
{
      public static DocumentViewModel op_Implicit(Document document)
      {
          Document document2 = new Document();
          document2.set_Id(document.get_Id());
          return op_Implicit(document);
      }
 }

// Nuestro Main quedaría así
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DocumentViewModel results;
        Document doc = new Document();
        results = DocumentViewModel.op_Implicit(doc); // Aquí es donde empieza todo el problema..
    }
}
```

¡Esto es una locura! La verdad que sí. La razón del *stack overflow* es justamente porque se está llamando al método `op_Implicit` de manera recursiva sin caso base.

El compilador generó este código erróneo por un despiste del programador, tal como lo dijeron en los comentarios, al sobrecargar el operador, el método debe retornar un objeto de tipo `DocumentViewModel`.

Siguiendo las correcciones que menciona la respuesta de *Ronquillo*, el código de ejemplo (el que emula el comportamiento del problema) quedaría así:

```cs
using System;

class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class DocumentViewModel
{
      public string Id { get; set; }
    
      public static implicit operator DocumentViewModel(Document document)
      {
           return new DocumentViewModel
           {
               Id = document.Id,
           };
      }
 }
```

Al convertir el código anterior a [IL](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQO0AIARAewGMBXAWwFMA7YHAbxwEhkBmfZdABnwEkY+RvgDm1YAG58AZwnSAvjiW5sBEhRr0AamGoB3ALLEY1CExz4r1jl14ChI8VNnz8K6/kueunbgDZ8MEoABwgwUjBgfGIQ6gAnAENgYniiMio6YF0DY1MIAAoNTPp8GAytYABKb09mbB9G5AB2fFoDdM0snKMTM1rGq3rBkcF8AF4yiqyAOkEoAcGFSUX3SxU8P1Q7ZotsNlRUVnqWFmLKnryzfHjqGXIIYBkV/bPp0vLSCbaO86yCqovEa3e6PGTfT7SVgqBRAA==):

```
    .method public hidebysig specialname static 
        class DocumentViewModel op_Implicit (
            class Document document
        ) cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x207c
        // Code size 24 (0x18)
        .maxstack 3
        .locals init (
            [0] class DocumentViewModel
        )

        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: newobj instance void DocumentViewModel::.ctor()
        IL_0006: dup
        IL_0007: ldarg.0
        IL_0008: callvirt instance string Document::get_Id()
        IL_000d: callvirt instance void DocumentViewModel::set_Id(string)
        IL_0012: nop
        // La recursión infinita desapareció... 
        IL_0013: stloc.0
        IL_0014: br.s IL_0016

        IL_0016: ldloc.0
        IL_0017: ret
    } // end of method DocumentViewModel::op_Implicit
```

Efectivamente, el compilador ya no genera ningún código erróneo. Como se puede ver, el método `op_Implicit` no se llama a sí mismo de manera indefinida. El *stack overflow* desapareció.

El código IL anterior lo podemos entender mejor así:

```cs
class DocumentViewModel
{
      public string Id { get; set; }

      public static DocumentViewModel op_Implicit(Document document)
      {
           DocumentViewModel documentViewModel = new DocumentViewModel();
           documentViewModel.Id = document.Id;
           return documentViewModel;
      }
 }
```

Ahora sí el código que genera el compilador tiene sentido y el programa funcionará correctamente.

Comment: tremenda respuesta!

Answer (score 3):

Gracias al comentario de @Gbianchi se dió con el error.

El error, en pocas palabras, consiste en que, mi clase `DocumentViewModel`, en su conversión implícita, está esperando devolver un objeto tipo `DocumentViewModel`, cuando está devolviendo un objeto tipo `Document`, entonces, al devolver `Document`, se llama al constructor de donde está saliendo, provocando un loop no esperado, que es lo que dispara la excepción.

Para corregirlo, la conversión implícita debería devolver `DocumentViewModel`, de la siguiente manera:

```
public class DocumentViewModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// ID
        /// </summary>
        public string Id { get; set; } //se añade parámetro ID al documentViewModel, esto no estaba antes.
        
        /// <summary>
        /// implicit model
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="document"></param>
        public static implicit operator DocumentViewModel(Document document)
        {
            return new DocumentViewModel //se cambia lo que se retorna al tipo correcto.
            {
                Id = document.Id,
            };
        }
    }
```

Con este cambio, el programa corre con normalidad. ¡Muchas gracias por la ayuda! :D